# Ordering my LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list of companies (joined to categories), in which i search by free text input and normally order the results by name / alphabetically.

But, when the returned companies are linked to a certain category (the id's of these more important categories are in a List), i want to primarily order the results with the companies from those categories on top and secondary ordering should be alphabetically.

How can i add this ordering?

```
    List<int> importantCategories = new List<int>() { 14, 99, 4428 };

    var companies = (from c in context.Companies
                     join ct in context.Categories on c.CategoryId equals ct.CategoryId
                     where ct.Active == true 
                     && c.Name.Contains(freeTextFilter)
                     orderby c.Name
                       --- if company is from category 14, 99, 4428 
                           then the ordering should place those above the rest
                     select c);
```

I took out a couple of lines from the query, but added one of those after the questions why i was not using the joined Categories table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
List<int> importantCategories = new List<int>() { 14, 99, 4428 };

var companies = (from c in context.Companies
                 join ct in context.Categories on c.CategoryId equals ct.CategoryId
                 where c.Name.Contains(freeTextFilter)
                 orderby importCategories.Contains(ct.CategoryID) ? 0 : 1, c.Name
                 select c);
```

or if you want the category to cause the order too then you might try this:

```
orderby importCategories.Contains(ct.CategoryID) ? ct.CategoryID : 4429, c.Name
```

4429 is just max value of the list + 1 which could be calculated dynamically.

As suggested this will work too, but not if you want to order by categoryID:

```
orderby !importCategories.Contains(ct.CategoryID) , c.Name
```

Is there a reason why ct is never used?

Comment: Do you even need that ternary? Won't ordering by `bool` work too?

Comment: @svick - I like it... off to test (which I didn't do :(

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
orderby (importantCategories.Contains(ct.CatetoryId) 
                            ? 0
                            : 1),
         c.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you need to do the join since you're not actually using any data from the category.  You're only using the category id for filtering and the `Company` contains that data already.  Second, you should use `OrderBy` with a custom key selector and a `ThenBy` so that you can get alphabetical within category.  This should due it using the fluent syntax.

It first orders by category id, but only if they are in the specified categories, other entries are considered the same (`int.MaxValue`).  Then it orders by `Name` within the category selections.  If you don't care about the order of the categories for the first section you can use `c => categories.Contains(c.CategoryId) ? 0 : 1` as the key selector.

```
var categories = new int[] { 14, 99, 4428 };

var companies = context.Companies
                       .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(freeTextFilter))
                       .OrderBy(c = categories.Contains(c.CategoryId) 
                                        ? c.CategoryId 
                                        : int.MaxValue)
                       .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ThenBy: here is an example

```
 List<string> strings = new List<string> { "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

        var result = strings.OrderByDescending(x => x == "e")
                            .ThenByDescending(x => x == "c")
                            .ThenBy(x=>x);
```

This gives "e", "c", "a", "b", "d", "f"

I think you could apply that to your problem to get the correct ordering.

Comment: @Hogan - In what way would this 'not work'? Try executing the code - works on my machine! This is an example of ordering by specific things and then having the rest of the ordering continue as normal - which is the OP's problem. This is not a complete re-work of the OP's question with a re-write of the code. As stated in the proposed answer - this can be applied to the problem to provide a solution with a little bit of thought.

Comment: Right, except the problem is not see if a value equals another value (which your answer does quite well and shows nicely), the problem is to see if a value is contained in another list.  This does not address the contains aspect of the question which really only has one solution, use the Contains function.

Comment: There is no reason why the OrderBy expression could not execute the contains function. In my example it would be (where y = new List<string>{"e", "f"} var result = string.OrderBy(x=> y.Contains(x)).ThenBy(x=>x). Infact, if you look at the answer proposed by tvanfosson below, he proposes exactly that.

Comment: Just re-read that - let me try again without the typos ;) the code I put in my comment should be 
(where var y = new List<string> { "e", "c" };) 
var result = strings.OrderByDescending(x =>y.Contains(x)).ThenBy(x => x); 
Sorry about that, got distracted!

Comment: Exactly, you need the Contains.

Comment: For the OP's question, yes Contains() is the logical method to use. For the example I posted, you can specify each expression seperately or use anything that does the job that is a delegate like Func<bool> which includes Contains(). The code posted does work - and can be applied to the problem, by use of a Contains() if you will - and that was the point. I think the problem has long since been solved and continuing to debate this isn't helping anyone anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Hogan's answer only using extension methods and Lambda expressions rather than query syntax (although arguably this might be a case where query syntax is easier on the eyes).

```
var companies = context.Companies
    .Join(context.Categories, c => c.CategoryId, ct => ct.CategoryId, (c, ct) => c)
    .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(freeTextFilter))
    .OrderBy(c => importantCategories.Contains(c.CategoryId) ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

Assuming you may not really need the Join...

```
var companies = context.Companies
    .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(freeTextFilter))
    .OrderBy(c => importantCategories.Contains(c.CategoryId) ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: This is much slower than just using contains in the orderby statement -- two extra loops.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, I see that now (edited)... Basically I ended up with very similar to yours.